# Jquery calculate widths and se div tag

Tags: jquery, grid

I'm doing a grid system for a site. The markup lookes like this

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
</div>
```

The class grid is 33.3333333333% wide.

I want to insert a div every time the grid sums up to 100 or close to 100%. This way the markup would look like this

```
<div class="section">
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
        <div class="clear"></div> <!-- inserted div -->
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
    <div class="grid">

    </div>
       <div class="clear"></div> <!-- inserted div -->
</div>
```

This is what I have so far. My wrapper is max 972px wide

```
var grid = $('.grid');
var wrapper = $('.wrapper').width();

$(grid).each(function () {
    var gridWidth = $(this).width();
    var percentage = (gridWidth / wrapper)*100;


    console.log(percentage);
});
```

Can anyone help me ?

EDIT:
I added a screenshot, so you can see the issue. The fouth element has a margin-left, which is should not have. This is why I want to add a clear
[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this sort it self out if the each grid-element floats and have the same width. The forth element will not fit and will fall down on a separate row, below the others. Given that you have a fixed width on the wrapper. Or am I missing something here? Or do you do something more the with `clear` class than clearing the float?

Comment: the reason is that inside the grid I have a div element with a margin left. with some CSS, I declare that the first element should not  have a margin left. when the fouth elements drops down, because of float, it has a margin-left. therefore, if there was an clear tag, I would know when to set another margin-left: 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all there pay attention in some discrepancies in your code. In HTML you're using "section" class, in jQuery you're selecting ".wrapper".

And than you should try something like this:

```
$('.section').each(function() {

    var rowPixels = 0;
    $(this).find('.grid').each(function () {

        var gridWidth = $(this).width();
        rowPixels += gridWidth;

        if (rowPixels >= $('.section').width()) {
            $(this).after('<div class="clear"></div>');
            rowPixels = 0;
        }

    });

});
```

Comment: It is very close, alomost there. 

There is just one problem.
It needs to look in a section and do the each. Then go into the newxt and do a each. Otherwise the grids in different sections are added together. This results in adde clears, when not needed.

Comment: I updated your fiddler, and as you can see there is a problem

Comment: Johansrk, thanks for voting!) It was my first carma up here!)

Comment: Oh, enter in comments is sending)) Gotta one more house rule!) Well I see your edition and there's a lil' hardcode there. I think there is a lot of ways to optimize this code! If you're interested we can chat anywhere. Anyway - it should work now!)

Comment: Oh, it wasn't your update? I'm totally not agree with this. Now I understand what you need and try to rollback and edit the code.

Comment: Wow. You are my hero. It works perfect now.. I now have a rock solid responsive grid. I changed yours a bit, see my edit

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17628/discussion-between-johansrk-and-semyon-vyskubov)